# I can't add videos to my video playlist after upgrading to iOS 5

Tags: video, ios

I want to add a compatible video to my videos app on my iPhone (using iOS 5),  but when I sync my iPhone with iTunes, the video doesn't show up on the device.

The video is already added to the iTunes library, and in the "video" section of the used space, there is video content, but there's nothing in my video playlist on the phone itself.

Did I miss something? Is there something I don't know about the usage of separated video and music folders on iOS 5?

Answer (score 1):

It is very annoying and it took me some time to figure it out. Before iOS 5 it could be done in the device itself, in the ipod app.

Now you can still do it in, but only in Itunes: on the lft hand side just create a playlist and drag videos from the "Movies" section into the playlist created, then sync itunes with the device, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the Videos app and restarting it. I have to do this every time I sync, or the new videos don't show up in the phone.

To kill the app: exit the videos app, double click the home button to bring up the multitasking bar, hold your finger down on the videos app icon in the bar until the X appears, then tap the X. Click the home button to go back to normal, then tap the videos app to launch it again.